# What to do to minimize the condition of if else on controls

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, controls

[image]

I have grid view in which all question has been display from access database . now I want to perform the search operation in given text boxes ,user may enter the data in 1 text box or else in all text boxes ,depends upon user needs .**My question** is how many times condition has been give so that whatever user give information in any text box ,filtration is performed accordingly.

for eg : user gave only standard and marks than filtration must be perform where standard = "given value" and marks = "given value" only

I have given various condition on each control but its become too huge coding. now wants to minimize this so any suggestion must recommended.

**My Code:**

```
private void txt_marks_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string marks = Convert.ToString(txt_marks.Text);
            string q_type = Convert.ToString(cmbQType.SelectedValue);
            if (q_type.Contains("[") || q_type.Contains("]") || q_type.Contains("*") || q_type.Contains("%"))
            {
                q_type = replacestring(q_type);
            }
            if (btnlanguage.Text != "" && txt_sub.Text != "" && txt_std.Text != "" && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1 && txt_marks.Text != "")
            {
                DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Subject  Like '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%' and Standard Like '" + txt_std.Text.ToString() + "'and Chapter Like '" + btnlanguage.Text.ToString() + "%' and QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and Marks = '" + marks + "'");
                DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            else if (txt_marks.Text != "" && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1 && txt_sub.Text != "" && txt_std.Text != "")
            {
                DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and  Marks = '" + marks + "' and Subject  Like '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%' and Standard Like '"+ txt_std.Text.ToString()+ "'");
                DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }

            else if (txt_marks.Text != "" && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1 && txt_sub.Text != "")
            {
                DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and  Marks = '" + marks + "' and Subject  Like '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%'");
                DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            else if (txt_marks.Text != "" && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format(" QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "'  and Marks = '" + marks + "'");
                DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            else if (txt_marks.Text != "")
            {
                DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Marks = '"+ marks +"'");
                DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            else
            {
                load_grid_view();
            }
```

Similarly above coding has been done to every given control.

Thank you .

Comment: Jesus Christ that is certainly some code. On a side note if you do this `string marks = Convert.ToString(txt_marks.Text);`, why are you still using `txt_marks` everywhere?

Comment: Because txt_Marks combination with different controls gives different condition , suppose the user might given standard value marks value but not subject  or else user might give subject value but not standard value i wrote all the possible condition , 5 factorial conditions but wants to minimize all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @KMoussa and @Sid .
With your Combine Both suggestion I made a Dynamic query in function and call this function on every control and also like to share with this site .

**My function** :

```
public void searching_query()
        {
            string grid_query = "";
            int cnt_coma = 0;
            string q_type = "";
            if (txt_marks.Text != "")
            {
                string marks = Convert.ToString(txt_marks.Text);
            }
            if (cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                q_type = Convert.ToString(cmbQType.SelectedValue);
                // Removing the wild character in question type . 
                if (q_type.Contains("[") || q_type.Contains("]") || q_type.Contains("*") || q_type.Contains("%"))
                {
                    q_type = replacestring(q_type);
                }
            }
            // counting the number of fields has been enter ->(for entering "and" in between in query)
            {
                if (txt_std.Text != "")
                    cnt_coma = 1;
                if (txt_sub.Text != "")
                    cnt_coma = 2;
                if (Txt_chp.Text != "")
                    cnt_coma = 3;
                if (cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
                    cnt_coma = 4;
                if (txt_marks.Text != "")
                    cnt_coma = 5; 
            }
            // making query for searching . 

            if (txt_std.Text != "")
            {
                if (cnt_coma > 1)
                    grid_query = grid_query + "Standard Like  '" + txt_std.Text.ToString() + "' and ";
                else if (cnt_coma <= 1)
                    grid_query = grid_query + "Standard Like '" + txt_std.Text.ToString() + "'";
            }
            if (txt_sub.Text != "")
            {
                if (cnt_coma > 2)
                    grid_query = grid_query + "Subject Like  '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%' and ";
                else if (cnt_coma <= 2 )
                    grid_query = grid_query + "Subject Like  '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%' ";
            }
            if (Txt_chp.Text != "")
            {
                if (cnt_coma > 3)
                    grid_query = grid_query + "Chapter Like  '" + Txt_chp.Text.ToString() + "%' and ";
                else if (cnt_coma <= 3 )
                    grid_query = grid_query + "Chapter Like  '" + Txt_chp.Text.ToString() + "%'";
            }
            if (cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                if (cnt_coma > 4)
                    grid_query = grid_query + "QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and ";
                else if (cnt_coma <= 4 )
                    grid_query = grid_query + "QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "'";
            }
            if (txt_marks.Text != "")
            {
                grid_query = grid_query + "Marks = '" + Convert.ToString(txt_marks.Text) + "'";
            }

            //---------- Grid view Filteration 
            if (cnt_coma > 0)
            {             
                DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format(grid_query);
                DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            else
            {
                load_grid_view();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using some `Function` that take `n` arguments to do some checks?

```
private void txt_marks_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string marks = Convert.ToString(txt_marks.Text);
    string q_type = Convert.ToString(cmbQType.SelectedValue);
    char[] q_types = { '[', ']', '%'};

    if (ContainsChars(q_types, q_type))
    {
        q_type = replacestring(q_type);
    }
    if (NoEmpty(btnlanguage.Text, txt_sub.Text, txt_std.Text, txt_marks.Text) && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Subject  Like '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%' and Standard Like '" + txt_std.Text.ToString() + "'and Chapter Like '" + btnlanguage.Text.ToString() + "%' and QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and Marks = '" + marks + "'");
        DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
    else if (NoEmpty(txt_marks.Text, txt_sub.Text, txt_std.Text) && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and  Marks = '" + marks + "' and Subject  Like '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%' and Standard Like '"+ txt_std.Text.ToString()+ "'");
        DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }

    else if (NoEmpty(txt_marks.Text, txt_sub.Text) && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "' and  Marks = '" + marks + "' and Subject  Like '" + txt_sub.Text.ToString() + "%'");
        DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
    else if (txt_marks.Text != "" && cmbQType.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format(" QuestionType Like '" + q_type + "'  and Marks = '" + marks + "'");
        DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
    else if (txt_marks.Text != "")
    {
        DataTable dt = main_ds.Tables[0];
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Marks = '"+ marks +"'");
        DGV_View.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
    else
    {
        load_grid_view();
    }
}

public static bool NoEmpty(params string[] strings)
{
   return strings.All( x => x != string.Empty );
}

public static bool ContainsChars(IEnumerable<char> chars, string toTest)
{
    return chars.Any(x => toTest.Contains(x));
}
```

Please note that I've written it with `notepad++` so I don't have typo checks, so excuse me if there's any typo

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can store the field query in the `Tag` property of each control (e.g. `txt_marks.Tag` would be set to `"Marks ='{0}'"`) then you can define an extensiom method to get the query from a `TextBox` and another for the drop down, something like:

```
internal static string GetQuery(this TextBox textBox)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)) return string.Empty;
    return string.Format(textBox.Tag.ToString(), textBox.Text)
}

internal static string GetQuery(this ComboBox cmbBox)
{
    if(cmbBox.SelectedIndex == -1) return string.Empty;
    return string.Format(cmbBox.Tag.ToString(), cmbBox.SelectedValue)
}
```

Then you can just loop through the controls, call `GetQuery` and do a `string.Join("and ", controlQueries.Where(q => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))`